# javascript add a floating div quiz button

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have created client side quiz using javascript

I want to add the following functionality to the page

1) There is a button START QUIZ at center of quiz DIV and if user scrolls the page then the START QUIZ button DIV is always visible on the down side of main menu

2)If user started the quiz and scrolls the page then CONTINUE QUIZ button DIV should be visible on the down side of main menu

Please reply. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
Apply fixed position

position:fixed 

in your stylesheet for your div id or class.
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create variables!

1. If user has started then `var quiz = "start";`
2. If user has to start then `var quiz = "tostart";`.

Now the HTML would be:

```
<button class="button"></button>
```

The JS (jQuery) would be:

```
if(quiz == "start") {
  $('.button').text('Continue'); 
  $('.button').css('position', 'fixed'); 
  /* add other parameters as per need */
} else if(quiz == "tostart") {
  $('.button').text('Start'); 
  $('.button').css('position', 'fixed'); 
  /* add other parameters as per need */
}
```

For basic JS

```
if(quiz == "start") {
  var button = document.getElementsByClassName("button");
  button.innerHTML = "Continue";
  button.style.position = "fixed";
  /* and same thing for the other half */
}
```

You can always alter the value of the variable!